# Magento- Resize Images on the Category Grid and List pages

Tags: image, magento, thumbnails

I need to change the default image size of 135x135 image size on the category page to 187x140. I've edited two .phtml files:

catalog>product>new.phtml 
and 
catalog>product>list.phtml

and changed the following
`<a href="...$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->***resize(187,140) ?>" width="187" height="140"*** alt="...></a>`

I also changed the css
.products-grid `.product-image { display:block; width:187px; height:140px; margin:0 0 0px; }`

I have cleared the cash, logged in and logged out. My image placeholders are uploaded and they were the correct size when uploaded.

I do not understand why my image size is still showing as 135x135.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the /var/session and /var/cache folders. That normally clears any caching issues.

Comment: If that doesn't work, also make sure you're editing the correct template and css files and that the inspected image has the correct native size. Just for safe measure, clear browser cache (even though the file name should be different).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This problem seemed to fix itself at random. I did however delete the VS Ajax extension. So I'm guessing this was the cause. Even though I had disabled it for the time being I needed to delete the folders from app/code/community and my template, layout, css folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even after clearing image cache, var cache en sessions. It appeared that another module was overwriting the theme's list.phtml file. Check out your /app/design/frontend/default/default/template folder for modules that overwrite your theme's file.